# Creating and filling data for json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, class, json.net

So... I got these two following classes for json file

```
    public class Scorebot
    {
        public string Messagedata { get; set; }
        public string CurrentScoreCt { get; set; }
        public string CurrentScoreT { get; set; }
        public string TeamNameCt { get; set; }
        public string TeamNameT { get; set; }
        public Players[] PlayersCt { get; set; }
        public Players[] PlayersT { get; set; }
    }

    public class Players
    {
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string Weapon { get; set; }
        public string Health { get; set; }
        public string Armor { get; set; }
        public string Money { get; set; }
        public string Adr { get; set; }
        public string Kills { get; set; }
        public string Assists { get; set; }
        public string Deaths { get; set; }
    }
```

the following json should looking like:

```
{
  "messagedata": "kyoto killed SEGADOBR",
  "currentscoreCT": "10",
  "currentscoreT": "10",
  "teamnameCT": "CT",
  "teamnameT": "T",
  "playersCT": [
            {
              "Nickname": "SEGADOBR",
              "Weapon": "ak47",
              "Health": "100",
              "Armor": "100",
              "Money": "16000",
              "ADR": "13.6",
              "Kills": "16",
              "Assists": "5",
              "Deaths": "18"
            }
  ],
  "playersT": [
            {
              "Nickname": "kyoto",
              "Weapon": "ak47",
              "Health": "100",
              "Armor": "100",
              "Money": "16000",
              "ADR": "13.6",
              "Kills": "999",
              "Assists": "5",
              "Deaths": "18"
            }
  ]     
}
```

How to access variables (Messagedata, CurrentScoreCt, CurrentScoreT, TeamNameCt and TeamNameT) i understood. But what i should do to fill elements in this (Players[] PlayersCt, Players[] PlayersT), how to access them correctly?

As i understand it should look like this

```
Scorebot.PlayersCt[i].Nickname = "something"
```

But it didn't work. How to do it?

Comment: `But it didn't work.` what does it mean? What issue you are facing ? Are you trying to create json from class object or create object from json?

Comment: When i'm starting program i getting  `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
with following code     `Scorebot.PlayersT = new Players[5];
    Scorebot.PlayersCt = new Players[5];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     Scorebot.PlayersCt[i].Nickname = "Noone";
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     Scorebot.PlayersT[i].Nickname = "Noone";
    }`

Comment: @Nicerok1 and have you initialized any of those variables/arrays? I'm guessing not. Reference types will default to `null` until you assign values to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm trying to create json from class "Scorebot" and it worked until the moment I started trying to fill the array PlayersT and PlayersCt

Comment: @Nicerok11 We know you are, but you need to initialize classes. Otherwise you'll be trying to serialize nothng, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: And did you initialize `PlayersT`?

Comment: i initialized them like this `Scorebot.PlayersT = new Players[5];
    Scorebot.PlayersCt = new Players[5];`
isn't this correct?

Comment: That initializes the array, so you have an array of 5 `null` values. You can then initialize each index of the array to contain an object (e.g. `Scorebot.PlayersCt[0] = new Players();`)

Comment: And then im trying to fill elements to not get null reference exception `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { Scorebot.PlayersCt[i].Nickname = "Noone"; } for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { Scorebot.PlayersT[i].Nickname = "Noone"; }`

Comment: Search for _"Example: Array of class objects"_ in the linked "What is a NullReferenceException" duplicate. Essentially you create 5 boxes, and then try to take something out of them, but you only have boxes, you don't have anything inside them. You have to put something inside the box before you can take it out.

Comment: You need to do `Scorebot.PlayersCt[i] = new Players();` before `Scorebot.PlayersCt[i].Nickname = "Noone";`

Answer (score 1):

You can fill in your object like this:

```
var scoreBot = new Scorebot
{
    Messagedata = "kyoto killed SEGADOBR",
    CurrentScoreCt = "10",
    CurrentScoreT = "10",
    TeamNameCt = "CT",
    TeamNameT = "T",
    PlayersCt = new Players[]
    {
        new Players
        {
            Nickname = "SEGADOBR",
            Weapon = "ak47",
            Health = "100",
            Armor = "100",
            Money = "16000",
            Adr = "13.6",
            Kills = "16",
            Assists = "5",
            Deaths = "18"
        }
    },
    PlayersT = new Players[]
    {
        new Players
        {
            Nickname = "kyoto",
            Weapon = "ak47",
            Health = "100",
            Armor = "100",
            Money = "16000",
            Adr = "13.6",
            Kills = "999",
            Assists = "5",
            Deaths = "18"
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can simply convert it to JSON using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
var jsonScoreBot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreBot);

Console.WriteLine(jsonScoreBot);
// {"Messagedata":"kyoto killed SEGADOBR","CurrentScoreCt":"10","CurrentScoreT":"10","TeamNameCt":"CT","TeamNameT":"T","PlayersCt":[{"Nickname":"SEGADOBR","Weapon":"ak47","Health":"100","Armor":"100","Money":"16000","Adr":"13.6","Kills":"16","Assists":"5","Deaths":"18"}],"PlayersT":[{"Nickname":"kyoto","Weapon":"ak47","Health":"100","Armor":"100","Money":"16000","Adr":"13.6","Kills":"999","Assists":"5","Deaths":"18"}]}
```

And now you can simply call `scoreBot.PlayersCt[i].Nickname = "Noone"` to update the object as well. Note that only one element exists in `PlayersCt`, so `i` must be 0 to avoid a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Thanks! But i still have some questions. I will write you an email so can you help me in your free time?

Comment: @Nicerok11 You can ask your questions here. I'm happy to assist you more, as long as its still relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in Scorebot
instead of using an array, use a generic list.

```
public class Scorebot
    {
        public string Messagedata { get; set; }
        public string CurrentScoreCt { get; set; }
        public string CurrentScoreT { get; set; }
        public string TeamNameCt { get; set; }
        public string TeamNameT { get; set; }
        public List<Players> PlayersCt { get; set; }
        public List<Players> PlayersT { get; set; }
    }

    public class Players
    {
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string Weapon { get; set; }
        public string Health { get; set; }
        public string Armor { get; set; }
        public string Money { get; set; }
        public string Adr { get; set; }
        public string Kills { get; set; }
        public string Assists { get; set; }
        public string Deaths { get; set; }
    }
```

then just create an object of Scorebot as well player class
like

```
Scorebot objModel = new Scorebot();
List<Players> PlayersCt = new List<Players>();
List<Players> Playersst = new List<Players>();
```

Fill your desire data dynamically in those objects.
then

```
objModel.PlayersCt = PlayersCt ;
objModel.Playersst = Playersst ;
```

then at last just convert that object into a JSON string like

```
var jsonScoreBot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objModel);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how i supposed to fill data into that list?
So i need to create a new player in list and then fill properties(nickname, etc.)?